# TF2 tensorflow hub retrained model - expanded my training datababase twofold, accuracy dropped 30%, after cleaning up data dropped 40%

Tags: tensorflow

I need assistance as a ML beginner. I have retrained TF2's model using `make_image_classifier` through tensorflow hub (command line approach).
My very first training:

[image]

I have immediately retrained the model once again as this one's predictions did not satisfy me -> using 4 classes instead and achieved 85% val.accuracy in Epoch 4/5 and 81% val.accuracy in Epoch 5/5. Because the problem is complex, I have decided to expand upon my db, increasing the number of data fed to the model.

I have expanded the database more than twofold! The results are shocking and I have no clue what to do. I can't believe this.

[image]

If anything - the added data is of much better quality, relevance and diversity, and it is actually obtained by myself - a human "discriminator" to the 2nd model's preformance (the 81% acc. one). If I knew how to do it, which is a second question - I would simply add this "feedback data" to my already working model. But I have no idea how to make it happen - ideally, I'd want to give feedback to the bot, allowing it to train once again on the additional data, it understanding that this is a feedback rather than a random additional set of data. However training a new model with updated data from scratch I'd like to try out anyways.

How do I interpret those numbers? What can be wrong with the data? Is it the data what's wrong at all, which is my assumption? Why is the training accuracy below 0.5?? What could have caused the drop between Epoch 2/5' and Epoch 3/5 starting the downfall? What are common issues and similar situations when something like this happens?

I'd love to understand what happened behind the curtains on a more lower level here but I have difficulty, I need guidance. This is as discouraging as the first & second training were encouraging.

Possible problems with the data I can see - but I can't believe they could cause such a drop especially because they were there during 1st&2nd training that went okay:

- 1-5% images can be in multiple classes (2 classes or maximum 3) - in my opinion this is even encouraged for the problem, as the model imitates me, and I want it to struggle with finding out what it is about certain elements that caused me to classify them as two+ simultaneous classes. Finding out features in them that made me think they'd satisfy both.
- 1-3% can be duplicates.
- There's white border around the images (since it didn't seem to affect the first trainings I didn't bother to remove it)

The drop is 40%.

I will now try to use Tensorflow's tutorial to do it through a script rather than using command line, but seeing such a huge drop is very discouraging, I was hoping to see an increase, after all that's a common suggestion to feed a model more data and I have made sure to feed it quality additional data.. I appreciate every single suggestion for fine-tuning the model, as I am a beginner and I have no experience with what might work and what most probably won't. Thank you.

EDIT: I have cleaned my data by:

- removing borders(now they are tiny, white, sometimes not present at all)
- removing dust
- removing artifacts which there were quite many in the added data!

Convinced the last point was the issue, I retrained. Results are even worse!

- 2 classes binary
  [image]
- 4 classes
  [image]

Comment: Two thoughts: "I would simply add this "feedback data" to my already working model. [..] it understanding that this is a feedback rather than a random additional set of data". => That is the basic of training a neural network that you have labels along with the input. So one new set of data (which is labelled) is used to train the model again. And yes, then you retrain the whole model. The new observation so to say has the same weight. Or why should it have more importance? So this is already so to say a "feedback", if you retrain it with the new labelled observation.

Comment: Regarding the general question of performance going down while expanding the data set: Sounds like the newly added data is more "difficult" to classify. Do you know what it looks like? Seem suspiciouse, like the new data is far more difficult to handle for the algorithm than the old data. " they were there during 1st&2nd training that went okay" => didn't get this, but you did not use it in the first training?

Comment: Ah, I think you mean epoch 1 and 2. I see.

Comment: I've experimented with other models (mainly mobilenet v3) and have been able to achieve 80+% on some of the epochs with both 2class and 4class training. I'm a bit shocked as to the discrepancy - the range of training can be anywhere from 40-80%, (even 10% if I mess something up) depending on params and training steps I specify. Is it something to expect during my ML learning or is there still something wrong with the data? What would your presumption be?

Comment: Mh, from my point of view this is a clear thing. Of course your results highly depend on the architecture and even small changes in the layers or parameters can make a big change. Using pretrained models like mobilenet is a good idea and these are indeed very good models. So it will likely lead to good results and you will need a very specific well trained model to your specific sceanario to beat these models. So I would say this is something to expect.